# Regex / Replacing Text Issue in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

I am trying to find the words `NOUN|ADJECTIVE|VERB` in the file, and then prompt the user to enter new words and replace the words with the user input, which I'll write to a new text file.

It almost works, but the text file I am using (which has 2 nouns) prompts the user for both of the 2 nouns, yet whatever the input for the first NOUN was is outputted in both noun positions in the file.

**For example:**

```
Please enter a: ADJECTIVE
blue

Please enter a: NOUN
cup

Please enter a: VERB
go

Please enter a: NOUN
coat
```

The blue panda walked to the cup and then go. A nearby cup was
unaffected by these events.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(NOUN|ADJECTIVE|VERB)') #sets pattern
with open('story.txt', 'r') as f: #opens file to read
    contents = f.read() #assigns readable info to variable
    matches = pattern.findall(contents) #makes list of matches
for match in matches: #iterate over every match
    cual = str(match) 
    print("Please enter a:", cual) 
    replacement = input() #get input to replace the match
    contents = contents.replace(match, replacement) #replace with input
f.close() 
with open('story2.txt', 'w') as g: #write new text into new file
    g.write(contents)
g.close()
with open('story2.txt', 'r') as f:
    finished = f.read()
    print(finished) #print new text
```

Comment: You are replacing all occurrences of e.g. NOUN with the value input by the user. Try adding `,maxreplace=1` to the `contents.replace()` parameters.

Comment: Can you show us a few lines from the **story.txt**?

Comment: The ADJECTIVE panda walked to the NOUN and then VERB. A nearby NOUN was
unaffected by these events.

Comment: @barny   Where, specifically, do I add it? I tried adding it after the other 2 arguments but it gave an error message. I guess I'm adding it to the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Remitto try this:

```
contents = contents.replace(match, replacement, 1)
```